# detect broken image with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have tried many of the solutions using javascript to detect broken images but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Select 'jquery' from the dropdown box here to see the broken images:-

http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/getpocket/view.html

The code for the site is here:-

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Insights Lab</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
    <style>
    ul li { color: red;}
    .emphasis { color: green;}
    .code {color: #3387B5}
    body { font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; }
p { font-size: 14px; color:#999; }
h2 { font-size: 18px; 
color:#666;
}
.view {
  bottom: 10;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
    #art {
      position: relative;
    width:220px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:5px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
    </style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function onImgErrorSmall(source)
{
source.src = "http://www.forbes.com/favicon.ico";
// disable onerror to prevent endless loop
source.onerror = "";
return true;
}

function onImgErrorLarge(source)
{
source.src = "http://www.forbes.com/favicon.ico";
// disable onerror to prevent endless loop
source.onerror = "";
return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

function baseurl($url) {

// you can add more to it if you want
$urlMap = array('com', 'co.uk','it','org','net','ca','io','me','edu','ac.uk','info','au');

$host = "";
//$url = "http://www.google.co.uk";

$urlData = parse_url($url);
$hostData = explode('.', $urlData['host']);
$hostData = array_reverse($hostData);

if(array_search($hostData[1] . '.' . $hostData[0], $urlMap) !== FALSE) {
  $host = $hostData[2] . '.' . $hostData[1] . '.' . $hostData[0];
} elseif(array_search($hostData[0], $urlMap) !== FALSE) {
  $host = $hostData[1] . '.' . $hostData[0];
}

return $host;

}
function highlight($text, $words) {
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
    if(!$m)
        return $text;
    $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';
    return preg_replace($re, '<span class="code">$0</span>', $text);
}

$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('mysql.site.com','un','pw');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("getpocket", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `given_title` like '%".$q."%' or `excerpt` like '%".$q."%' order by `time_added` desc";



$result = mysql_query($sql);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $tit = highlight($row['given_title'], $q);
  $exc = highlight($row['excerpt'], $q);
  $url = $row['resolved_url'];
  ?> 
    <div id = "art">
    <h2><?php echo $tit;?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $exc;?></p>

    <div class = "view">

    <a href ="<?php echo $url;?>" target='_blank'><img src = "http://<?php echo baseurl($url);?>/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" onerror="onImgErrorSmall(this)"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
mysql_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: You need to post pertinent code only, and define what you mean by "doesn't work." What do you expect from the pertinent code? What do you get instead? Are there any errors showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this before `</body>`

```
<script>
    function onImgErrorLarge(orig_img) {
        var img = new Image();

        img.src =  orig_img.src;

        img.onerror = function() {
            orig_img.src = 'other source';
            //alert('Img not found');
        };
    }



function showUser(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

            for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) 
               onImgErrorLarge(imgs[i]);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getarticles.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}



</script>
```

Comment: so do I remove my existing code? Also, does the function onImgErrorLarge stay in the head and the var imgs code stay before </body> ?

Comment: onImgErrorLarge can be at any place, if this works for you you can use it, I give up my code rights..

Comment: I checked it manualy, and it worked.. I added the onImgErrorLarge function and then executed the loop.. and it worked, anyway I did another update

Comment: ok - I see it is now working here http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/getpocket/getarticles.php however I need it working on the page that querys the database from here http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/getpocket/view.html - should the code be in view.html or getarticles.php?

Comment: whoo hoo that works - ratrher than popup an alert, how do I set the src to something else? Is it -     function onImgErrorLarge(src) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src =  src;
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert('Img not found');
   src = "http://www.forbes.com/favicon.ico";
        };
    }

Comment: first of all, move the function onImgErrorLarge to the same place showUser function (at the head)..  I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.error()](http://api.jquery.com/error/) API to detect broken images.

```
jQuery('img').error(function() {
        //Do stuff if broken image found
    });
```

This article will also help you:
[Remove Broken Images using jQuery](http://www.levihackwith.com/automatically-remove-broken-images-from-the-dom-using-jquery/)